# Set Y-axis in FLOT depending on value

Tags: flot

How can I set the min and max value of the Y-axis, when it is depending on the highest value, for example 32 (degrees celsius) than I would like a max value of a few degrees higher, with scale linesof 5 degreez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation on axes costumization](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) for this:

- First, try setting the `tickSize: 5` option
- If flot's automatic tick generation still does not what you want, try also setting the `max` and `min` options. For `max` you could calculate the next multiple of 5 greater than your data maximum (something like `max = 5 * (Math.floor(32/5) + 1)`).
- If all this fails, use the `ticks` option and give it an array with the specific values you want to have on your axis (something like `[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]`).